# SpecFlow Parallel execution in same or multiple test agent

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest, specflow

How to execute specflow test case parallel on the same test agent using MS test

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**Assembly Attribute**

This option is suitable if you have only one test assembly and code is modifiable.
If you can add below assembly attribute anywhere in your assembly (e.g. properties.cs file or any test class file), you should be able to get the specflow tests running paralely.

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 0, Scope = ExecutionScope.MethodLevel)]
```

**.runsettings file settings**

If you have multiple test assemblies you want to parellize you can create a file named .runsettings at the root of the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <MSTest>
    <Parallelize>
      <Workers>8</Workers>
      <Scope>MethodLevel</Scope>
    </Parallelize>
  </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

> There are 3 scopes of parallelization:
>
> (1) **ClassLevel** – each thread executes a TestClass worth of tests.
>   Within the TestClass, the test methods execute serially. This is the
>   default – tests within a class might have interdependency, and we
>   don’t want to be too aggressive.
>
> (2) **MethodLevel** – each thread executes a TestMethod.
>
> (3) **Custom** – the user can provide a plugin implementing the
>   required execution semantics. This is presently not yet supported but
>   mentioned because – like all of MSTest V2 – we have designed the
>   feature with extensiblity in mind.

Refer [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/01/30/mstest-v2-in-assembly-parallel-test-execution/) for more details

Comment: Don't use MethodLevel with SpecFlow. You will get errors (we are not thread safe on this level). You need to use ClassLevel.